# how to save image using bitmap i tried this code

Tags: dot

string billno = lblBillNo.ToString();

```
        //memoryImage.Save("D:/rajkiran/" + lblBillNo.Text + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        memoryImage.Dispose();
```

Comment: Please tag with the correct language tags

Answer (score 1):

That code would appear to be trying to save as jpeg. 
And in anycase the line to save is commented out.

i would guess - but without details on what language / libraries you are using I cant be certain - that you mean something like

```
string billno = lblBillNo.ToString();

memoryImage.Save("D:/rajkiran/" + lblBillNo.Text + ".bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.bmp);
memoryImage.Dispose();
```

Which took precisely 2 seconds to find in google